# Multiple control buttons for a maximised MDI child in .NET WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, mdi

[MDI Bug http://www.dicu.com/pics/bug_mdi.jpg](http://www.dicu.com/pics/bug_mdi.jpg)

That's what I get when I try to automatically maximize MDI children.
The code is something like this:

```
this.IsMdiContainer = true;
child = new Form();
child.MdiParent = this;
child.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
child.Show();
```

Any ideas why do I get multiple control buttons ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can repro this partially.  Don't call the child's Show() method in the constructor, do it in the parent's Load event handler.  Not so sure about the off-kilter min/max/close icons.

Comment: I ran into this problem as well.  It happens on Vista and Windows 7, but does not happen on Window XP.

I was originally opening the MDI child in Maximized state.  Changing it to open in a normal state fixed the problem.  I'm able to maximize the MDI child at a later time without having these extra icons show up.

Comment: Thanks as well for that. I just wasted 2 hours trying to figure this one out, though I did have to pretty much move the whole Add Child routine to load, not just the Show. +1